# amplifyconfiguration.json and awsconfiguration.json not found by Xcode, how do I debug?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-amplify

I'm building an iOS app using Swift / Xcode. The app is functional and will build/run without errors when testing locally. I'm trying to archive a build so I can submit for App Store Review, but I'm getting an error that I haven't seen before:

"/Volumes/workspace/repository/amplifyconfiguration.json: No such file or directory"

"/Volumes/workspace/repository/awsconfiguration.json: No such file or directory"

I can't figure out how to debug for where this is located, as when I search for "amplifyconfiguration.json" in project, it doesn't exist. in any of the files. I believe it's in the Amplify package somewhere, but can't ID how it's getting that file path. The closest I can find is the "extension AmplifyConfiguration" file.

Has anybody ran into this or know how I can debug?

Answer (score 0):

When you created your project and run first time `amplify init` , you configured your BE environment and the file `awsconfiguration.json` and all the rest necessary files were automatically created in your project and with `amplify add <service name>` it adds all the AWS services you will need inside awsconfiguration.json again automatically.

In case you changed branch and did not commit these files to your branch or for whatever other reason the files are not there, try to run again `amplify init` and configure your BE environment again to create the necessary files.

Hope it helps